# jQuery how to set selector to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my problem:
I have sidebar which has 300px width, user can hide part of it and then sidebar may have 100px width. I would like to add class to element while sidebar is hidden, and when it is full I would like to remove class from that element.
When I hide part of sidebar script works good, but when I show it again. variable **element** is undefined.
Someone could explain me why is that?
Here is my function

```
function checkSidebarWidth()
{
    var sidebarWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
    var element;

    if(sidebarWidth <= 100){
        element = $('.sidebarWidth .nav > li > a.active').parents('ul').prev().children();
        element.addClass('active');
    }else{
        if(!typeof(element) === 'undefined'){
            element.removeClass('active');
        }
    }   
setTimeout(checkSidebarWidth, 100);
}
```

Comment: Everytime you call this function, you declare a new var named `element` which starts as undefined. If your sidebarWidth fails the first if condition, it stays undefined, therefore never entering the `else if`

Comment: @Willem OP is checking for element not undefined

Comment: if(!typeof(element) === 'undefined') should be if( !(typeof(element)==='undefined') )

Comment: @san.chez if(!element) should just be enough

Comment: Thanks gentlemen for explanation

Comment: @roasted yes it should. I only wanted to point out that:  ! has higher precedence then ===

Comment: @san.chez  good point, i didn't notice it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables don't persist beyond the function invocation. When your first call to the function ends, the value of `element` is swept away.

What you can do is declare `element` outside the scope of the function, and close over it in the function. That way its value persists between invocations. Alternatively, you can re-select the jQuery collection each time (which is **much** less efficient) by moving `element = $('.sidebarWidth .nav > l...` outside the conditional statement.

Yet another way to do this (and the approach I would prefer) would be to accept the collection as a parameter, and when you recursively schedule the function, pass the collection to it:

```
function checkSidebarWidth(element) {
    var sidebarWidth = $('.sidebar').width();

    if (sidebarWidth <= 100) {
        element.addClass('active');
    } else {
        element.removeClass('active'); //The conditional statement is no longer needed
    }   
    setTimeout(function(){checkSidebarWidth(element);}, 100);
}
```

Now you can evaluate the collection once, pass it on your first invocation, and stop worrying about it:

```
var sideBar = $('.sidebarWidth .nav > li > a.active').parents('ul').prev().children();
checkSidebarWidth(sideBar);
//Done! sideBar will keep circulating around inside checkSidebarWidth
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I'll keep it in mind and I promise do not ask such as newbie questions in future :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could assign `element` each time the function is called:

```
function checkSidebarWidth(element) {

//var element = $('.sidebarWidth .nav > li > a.active').parents('ul').prev().children();
if(sidebarWidth <= 100){
    element.addClass('active');
}else{
    element.removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I wanted

Comment: @user1409508 This approach is inefficient, since you're needlessly re-constructing the same collection on each iteration. Considering that your function runs once every 100ms, that is a huge performance hit.

Comment: @Asad -- I failed to notice the interval check, I've edited now to include element as a parameter, +1 to your answer -- OP, I would mark Asad's as the correct answer.